# Authenticate Cron Job on Spring Boot OAuth2 Server

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, cron, microservices

I have 2 microservices:

- the first one is an Authorization and Resource Server
- the second microservice is a Resource server with a cron job

That cron job make requests to the first microservice, but it needs a token in order to make requests to the first microservice.

How can i get a token for cron job?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Having said that: how do *other* services (or users) acquire such tokens? Your cron job shouldn't be any different than other services/users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a token from cron. Cron is nothing more then a time table to start an executable. You could, however, have the executable started by cron, providing a token.